# Playstore not downloading or updating anything

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow

My playstore is not working from my device. Whenever trying to download or update, it just shows 'waiting for downalod' and that loading bar spins forever around the app logo. No i do not have any connection issues. My internet is strong enough, and to check, I have used other wifi and also cellular data. I have tried already clearing data, disabling and enabling, restarting, reset settings etc. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tried clearing the app data and restarting yet it's not working. Perhaps did you check 'App download preference' in the setting? Once I set it to 'Over Wi-Fi only'. And later even after changing it back to 'Over any network' it kept saying 'waiting for download'.

And if it's regional issue, try checking it with a VPN. But before trying it with VPN, force close Play Store and clear the data.

Comment: well yes currently i managed to get it working with vpn. It is a regional issue. Hopefully they will fix it

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem (which happened suddenly and without me changing anything) after a Google Libraries update. It persisted for some time and after a couple of Google Libraries updates it was fixed and now everything is updating normally.

I had tried to clear caches, reset Google Play etc. but nothing had worked. I suppose this is a bug in Google services.

Comment: so, should I just wait for another update? Nothing is updating anyways

Comment: When I am moving with my car, I usually put the phone in airplane mode. I had seen that if I had put the phone in airplane mode for quite a while (say half an hour) the problem stopped and I could update for some reason (I know it sounds crazy but it happened). And the problem started happening again after I turned off my phone at night and turned it on again in the morning. You could do that experiment.

Comment: Google Libraries are automatically updated so maybe a future update will solve your problem. For me it took quite a while (2 months). In the meantime I did the workaround in my previous comment (which I accidentally discovered)

Comment: yeah I'll try that thanks

Comment: Please make a comment if the workaround works for you!

Comment: It seems to be a regional problem. Now, nobody from my country is being able to do the same. So I guess it will be fixed automatically in a while