# all google product app isn’t loading or working. what to do?

Tags: google-play-store, google, google-play-services, 8.0-oreo, google-apps

Google services like **Youtube, Gmail, assistant, Docs, google app** etc are not loading or working. The loading bar appears but nothing happens. Play store loads everything but when i click install it shows waiting for download and then nothing happens. The browser versions of all those products are working perfectly but those app versions are not working. I am currently running Oreo. Is there any possibility i can fix this? Here is a google assistant "something went wrong" screenshot

[image]

Comment: Possibly some problem with Play Services. Did you try restarting device? Also check `logcat`.

Comment: i restarted my device several times and also cleared play services app data but nothing changed.

Comment: I would assume that the cause is identical to this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221821. Looks like Google is rolling out some required support-library updates and if you have the wrong combination you are in trouble.

Comment: So it looks like i have to wait for the next update. But if that one won't work then i am doomed!? :'(